# Anime from the 80s with a man dressed like Robin Hood

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I'm trying to re-connect with an old anime, the title of which is unknown to me. It would've aired sometime in the mid-late 80s, possibly on cable, in the USA. The plot's been lost to time, but here are the few details I do remember:

- Begins with a flutist in the woods: A young man, dressed very much like a stereotypical Robin Hood (in green, probably with a feather in the cap).
- Forest critters become evil (glowing red eyes). Definitely includes squirrels or chipmunks.
- The antagonist looks and dresses rather like [evil Karl Rove](https://theconservativetreehouse.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/karl-rove-emporer.jpg). I believe he has a companion, but I can't remember the form. The pair sometimes get about by transforming into geometric shapes -- appearing like neon lights arranged into triangles, or perhaps spheres.
- At one point, a huge Colosseum-like building is forming (magically). The walls are composed of blockish "gingerbread-men" that end up fitting together somewhat like legos.

Does anyone know the episode or series title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing sounds more like a movie to me than a TV series, though other movies were made. The movie I'm thinking of is *Unico in the Island of Magic*.

Your forest flutist is Toby, though his wardrobe is a little different from your description:

[image: Toby playing the flute]

Evil Karl Rove is Lord Kuruku:

[image: Yeah, that's Evil Karl Rove, all right.]

But what really makes me think this is it are the Lego-like "gingerbread men" you describe: Lord Kuruku's living puppets.

[image: Here's one living puppet]

[image: And here's a bunch of them linking up into a wall]

There were a few other movies made, which may be where the red-eyed forest creatures are from; I don't remember those from this film.

Comment: 100%! Brilliant. Thank you. The evil forest creatures must've been a red herring, most likely from another Unico installment.